# how to provide file name to excel using python dataset?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, dataset

Newbie here.
I have 3 columns in my data. I am exporting the data to an excel and the file name needs to include all the 3 column names in it. Using dataframe and dataset here.
Ex- ProjectNo-Area-Division.
The problem is Area is 3 digits. Some areas are '000', '010', '020', '01A'
If i use the below line

```
file_name = final_dataframe['PROJECT NUMBER'].unique()[0] + '-' + str(final_dataframe['AREA'].unique()[0]) + '-' + str(dataset['DIVISION'].unique()[0]) + '.xlsx'
```

file_name = ProjectNo-0-DIVISION 
ProjectNo-10-DIVISION
ProjectNo-20-DIVISION
ProjectNo-01A-DIVISION respectively.
How can I get all 3 digits in the file name, irrespective of being 0.
TIA

Comment: thanks. i tried the same and it worked

Answer (score 1):

When you convert your areas to strings, the integer ones are losing their leading zeros. You can add them back using `zfill`:

```
file_name = final_dataframe['PROJECT NUMBER'].unique()[0] + '-' + str(final_dataframe['AREA'].unique()[0]).zfill(3) + '-' + str(dataset['DIVISION'].unique()[0]) + '.xlsx'
```